# Unhide worksheet within a macro does not work when workbook is protected

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with unprotecting / protecting a sheet when I run a macro.  I read a few posts stating that I should insert the `ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="my password"` bit before and then the `ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="my password"`, into the macro, but this has not worked.  Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="my password"
Sheets("sheet1").Select
Sheets("sheet2").Visible = True
Sheets("sheet2").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
Cells.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, skipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A1").Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\file.csv" _
    , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWindow.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
Sheets("sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="my password"
```

Comment: You shouldn't use activesheet at all, refer to the sheets and workbooks directly, I'd imagine that the wrong sheet/book being selected at the wrong time is your problem

Comment: On top of what @Hello said - maybe not unprotect the activesheet but a specific sheet.  `Sheets("sheet2").Unprotect Password:="my password"`

Comment: @HelloWorld thank you, that worked a treat.